# Apex Callout to LinkedIn 'Liking a Company Share' API

Tags: api, integration

I'm unable to like a linkedin company update post through the linkedin like API i.e.
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/commenting-and-liking-company-share

Please find my code below which i'm using for like a company post.

```
    Http h = new Http();
    String postParam ='';
    String method = 'PUT';
    string body1 ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><is-liked>true</is-liked>';
    string sharequery='http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key=UPDATE-c1756-5902360166031974400/is-liked';
    HttpRequest sharequery_req= new HttpRequest();   
    sharequery_req.setMethod(method);
    sharequery_req.setBody(body); 
    sharequery_req.setEndpoint(sharequery.replace('~','%7E'));
    sharequery_req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml'); 
{
//Linkedin authentication.
}
    HttpResponse share_response= h.send(sharequery_req);
    integer statuscode=share_response.getstatuscode();  //added so code format change works
```

Thanks

Comment: you refer to `body` in the setBody() method but you declared `body1`. The way to debug this is to verify you can send the REST call successfully using a REST testing client and then go back to SFDC Apex and verify each bit of your outbound message against the known, working REST hard-coded message